# Populating a tree recursively with database contents

Tags: c#, data-structures, reference, tree, recursive-datastructures

I am using an [ORM that uses POCOs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite).

Each table (class) contains references to other tables.

```
public class Table1 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public string FieldA { get; set; }
}

public Table2 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public Table1 FieldA { get; set; }
    public int FieldB { get; set; }
}

public Table3 {
    [AutoIncrement]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    [Index(Unique = true)]
    public List<Table2> FieldA { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Table2))]
    public int Table2_id { get; set; }
}
```

**How would I populate a tree of Table3 which unrolls the referenced Table2 and subsequent Table1 into subtrees?**

Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: Just realised that C# doesn't have the data-structures I take for granted built in. Fortunately [C5](https://github.com/sestoft/C5/) adds this much required feature-set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like this?

```
var root = new {TopLevelNodes = Table3.Select(t3=> new {Id = t3.Table2_id, SubLevel = t3.FieldA.Select(t2=>new {t2.FieldA})})};
```

Comment: Hmm, that might be it, thanks. Though can you talk me through what it is? - E.g.: is it nested Lists or an actual Tree?

Comment: Yes, linq plus anonymous classes, I do not see full picture what you are going to accomplish, but you may not need it at all, your class already related the way you want.